What are my options for filling a groove in a cutting board?
I was gifted a beautiful cutting board, which I love, but unfortunately it has a groove that catches food particles with every use.
I'd like to repair the board rather than replace it, but I lack the experience of wood repair to even know what my options are.
If this was just a cosmetic repair I'd probably go for a simple wood filler, but since the board is used daily for food prep I guess it also has to be a repair that can stand up to slicing and chopping, frequent scrubbing, and monthly oiling.
I also considered chiselling and sanding the groove so it was more of a smooth and easily wipeable depression, which would reduce the problem with food particles, but it would also mean reducing the board's flatness, something I value in a cutting board.
The last thing I've considered is to ream out and fill with a plug of wood. But here I feel out of my depth. I don't have access to specialist tools though I'd be fine buying less expensive DIY tools, like a knock-off dremel for example. If this is a good option, maybe I just need reassurance its doable for an enthusiast DIY-er.
You can see the dimensions of the groove in the image, its roughly 70mm long x 3mm wide x 1.2mm deep.
How would you repair this board?



Welcome to Woodworking Stack Exchange! Just checking, is there a reason the other side of the board can’t be used? (E.g. it has a lip or something to do with the finish?)

Also, are comfortable with sharpening and using chisels?

Hi stanch, yes the other side of the board has less useable surface with juice grooves and wider depressions presumably for serving food in. I could of course use this side, but much prefer the wider surface area of the side with the defect in question.

personally, I'd use some epoxy, fill it in, let it dry and sand it flat, you could use clear or put a little black dye in it.  once cured, epoxy is food safe.

"....and monthly oiling" A suitable wood repair will (should) withstand this but there's zero need to oil as it's completely unnecessary. The tradition with long-grain boards was to just wash and use, and boards of all sorts in multiple species have withstood decades of use without a single drop of oil applied as 'maintenance' (oiling is fundamentally about aesthetics, not function). In addition to being unnecessary for longevity there's strong evidence it's actually more hygienic — in short because the wood is free to dehydrate and kill residual bacteria when it dries out between uses.

Given how small this groove is I would personally use epoxy here but a wood patch is a v good option. You can tint epoxy easily (as covered in a few previous Answers) but that's primarily for aesthetics, if you don't mind being able to see the patch down the line it's not needed. You will need to very thoroughly clean and degrease the surface of the groove prior to dolloping on the epoxy. Epoxies can be expected to be food-safe in general (all hard finishes are) and this is a v small part of a large prep area, so food contact can be expected to be low anyway. If worried tho use a better epoxy.

As @bowlturner suggested in the comments, filling with epoxy is probably the easiest method. It can be transparent or tinted, and once it hardens you can cut the overflow away with a chisel or block plane or scrape or sand it.
Another approach is to fill with a wooden patch as you mentioned. If you have matching wood, you can make the groove almost invisible.
You do not need fancy tools at all, just a couple of chisels (4-6mm and 12-20mm), a hand saw and a smoothing or block plane (shorter sole is better). It does take some practice to do this cleanly, so I recommend trying the same on a test piece at least 3-4 times (ideally, using similar wood species, as each one cuts slightly differently).
Fitting a patch to an existing groove is possible, but too finicky to be practical imho. Instead, you will need to enlarge it first.
One option is to make an oversized patch with straight edges and trace it onto the wood around the groove (with a marking knife). Alternatively, you can enlarge the groove into a perfect rectangle, cut out a rectangular patch and gradually plane it down to fit.
The inlay technique is similar to any other inlay, including butterfly keys, on which there are a few videos online.
You will want to use a waterproof glue.
Finally, you would plane away the protruding part of the patch (a flush cut saw reduces the amount of planing needed).
Having written all this, I am not sure the neatness of a wooden repair is worth the trouble unless you want to practice your woodworking skills :)

+1. You should probably change probably to must, and water-resistant to waterproof (just for the common understanding of the word) since the OP mentions frequent scrubbing in the Q, and water-resistant versions of PVA aren't known to withstand frequent wetting/drying cycles over many years.

Thanks, updated! Would you recommend polyurethane glue over PVA for this application?

Foaming poly, like the original Gorilla, is 100% waterproof but the top-tier PVAs are used to construct boards in the first place by most board makers so there's no question they can withstand the conditions over time. However I'd personally use epoxy for the glue-in anyway, primarily because it is a gap-filling adhesive (which neither of the others are) so that the long-grain surface of the underneath of the patch is strongly adhered regardless of whether it fully seats or not.
